# Can you hide LG Magic Remote's cursor on webOS 2?

Tags: cursor, smart-tv

Can you decide against using the "air pointing" feature of LG Magic Remotes and use them as "normal" remotes on a webOS 2 TV?

When I pick it up, I don't want the cursor to become visible and move around with the remote.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Press "Back" button + "Home" button until mouse is disappear.
And press "Scroll" button until LED power button is blink. then the cursor will appear.

Comment: Thank god, this finally got rid of this annoying cursor! This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: @BlenderBender - I just bought an LG tv but dont understand the solution.  Can you tell me what you did to get rid of the LG Pointer completly?

Comment: @JonH Unfortunately, you can't _completely_ disable the pointer. Pressing/holding `back` and `home` button only disconnects the Magic Remote temporarily (thus removing the cursor). I say temporary, because it will reconnect and show the cursor again once you inevitably click on the scroll wheel button.

Answer (score 5):

According to a manual for the LG magic remote, "If you press buttons (left,right,up,down) while the pointer is
in use, the pointer will disappear from the screen
and Magic Remote will operate like a general
remote control."  Hope this helps.